# Modify React state variable after specified time

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, react-hooks

I want to delete some entries from an array after a specified amount of time. `notifications` should be changed immediately, but in practice it remains unchanged. Is there a way to achieve my goal?

```
const Notifications = props => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([
    { value: '123', time: Date.now() },
    { value: '456', time: Date.now() }
  ]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(notifications);
      let time = Date.now();
      let array = notifications.filter(function(item) {
        return time < item.time + 0;
      });
      setNotifications(array);
    }, 500);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return null
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is fine! the problem is where you're logging it.

All state updates are asynchronous. With hooks the updated value is exposed in the scope of your component only in the next `render` call. If you log outside your effect you should see the correct values

```
const Notifications = props => {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([
    { value: '123', time: Date.now() },
    { value: '456', time: Date.now() }
  ]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      let time = Date.now();
      let array = notifications.filter(function(item) {
        return time < item.time + 0;
      });
      setNotifications(array);
    }, 500);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return null
}

console.log(notifications);
```